# Can I apply for multiple visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, germany

I got an offer from an UK employer which required me to apply for exempt visa for 3 years, at that time the offer looked really cool but just before few days I got another offer from Germany which is sponsoring Blue Card visa for me which seems better than exempt visa.

I am confused because I have already submitted my passport for the exempt visa processing, is there any way I can proceed with Blue Card visa after I get my passport back with exempt visa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The UK is not part of the Schengen area, so it is a separate jurisdiction as far as matters of immigration are concerned.  There's no prohibition against having two visas, one from each jurisdiction, at the same time.  If you decline the job in the UK, however, you may need to submit your passport to get the exempt visa cancelled.  This would be true regardless of whether you apply for another visa elsewhere.

Comment: I am confused, first you told I can have multiple visas but then you told that I need to cancel the first one.

Comment: @CodeYogi the first visa is dependent on your accepting a specific job in the UK.  If you do not accept that job, then you cannot use the first visa.  I do not know whether you actually need to get a cancellation stamp on the first visa in that case.  But none of this has any bearing on your blue card application. Is that any clearer?

Comment: I got it, just the cancellation part is still confused.

Comment: I have appointment at the German embassy next month so, the exempt visa on my passport shouldn't affect my interview there right?

Comment: @CodeYogi they might ask you about why you have the exempt visa, in which case you should just tell them about the job in the UK and that you've decided you are not going to take it.  But having the UK visa is no barrier to getting a German visa.

Comment: So, I can fully concentrate on getting the Blue card visa and anyways before joining I need to cancel anyone of it. Also, just one more thing cancelling thing can affect my history?

Comment: @CodeYogi I don't know whether you need to cancel the exempt visa. Probably if you don't plan to go to the UK then you don't need to cancel it.  If you do want to go to the UK then you probably should.  But I'm just guessing.  Ask the UK consulate.  I doubt cancelling will have an adverse effect on your history since you have a legitimate reason for cancelling.

Comment: Cool, would contact you if there any other confusion, thanks,